# jQuery jcrop plugin: how to release?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jcrop

I'm using the brilliant [jcrop plugin](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) to implement image cropping.

However, there's one problem. I want the user to select an area, and then see a dialog box. When they enter something into the dialog box and click OK, I want them to return to an image with nothing selected.

This is my code:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    var jcrop_api = $.Jcrop('#cropbox',{
        boxWidth: 1400,
        onSelect: showAlert
    });
});
function showAlert(c)
{
    var structidx = prompt("Enter number here: ", "");
    if (structidx!=null && structidx!="") {
                // TODO: some handling here
        alert("Entry has been saved");
        jcrop_api.release();
    } else {
        jcrop_api.release();            
    }
};
```

However, with this, when the user clicks OK or Cancel on the prompt, they return to an image that is still actively 'selecting'. As they move the mouse, it continues to select - they can't select a new area. Which feels broken.

I think it's a javascript flow problem - `showAlert` is exiting and returning me to the browser's previous state, i.e. with an area selected - but I don't know how to get round it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
  // function definition first
  function showAlert(c) {
    var structidx = prompt("Enter number here: ", "");
    if (structidx!=null && structidx!="") {
      // TODO: some handling here
      alert("Entry has been saved");
    }
    jcrop_api.release();
  }

  // make a global variable by leaving off the "var" keyword
  jcrop_api = $.Jcrop('#cropbox',{
    boxWidth: 1400,
    onSelect: showAlert
  });
});
```

Comment: @UtsavUpadhyay This thread is more than ten years (!) old. Please ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot grab the API this way. Try this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  var jcrop_api = $.Jcrop('#cropbox',{...});
});
```

Also note you'll need to declare your callback function(s) in the same scope as the `jcrop_api` variable if they reference it. That is not the case in your example code.

Comment: As the author of Jcrop, I can assure you that this is correct code. I suspect your problem may be variable scoping given your original example. Tomalak re-stated the complete code structure I was describing.

Comment: Yes, that code fixed it, thank you! It was indeed my variable scoping.